# Is there a simple zero knowledge proof of $x$ for $b=x^x\pmod p$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, zero-knowledge-proofs

We have a multiplicative cyclic group $G$ which is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})∗$. There are two parties, Alice and Bob:

If:

1. Alice knows: $b$ and $x$ such that $x^x = b$;
2. Bob knows: $b$.

Then what's the easiest non-interactive way Alice can prove to Bob the knowledge of $x$ without leaking $x$?

Comment: [here](http://www.di.ens.fr/~bresson/papers/BreSte02.pdf‎) Section 3.2. is a straightforward way to do so.

Comment: The changing of the question makes DrLecter's answer seem not applicable. The original statement of $a^{(x^2)}=b$ was solved by that paper, $x^x=b$ isn't.

Comment: @tylo Ah, didn't realize that the question has changed. SDL could you elaborate where you would need such a proof.

Comment: @SDL could you elaborate where you would need such a proof. Exponentiation of a group element with a group element of the same group does not really make sense to me.

Comment: If you fix the group to be $Z_p$ it might make sense. I don't have the time right now to write a full answer, but I think there is no such ZKP: In general, there is no relation between $x^x$ and $y^y$, which could be expressed as a polynomial of $x,y$ or a similar construction. Something like this is part of DSA/ ElGamal signatures, where you have something like $p(x)^{q(x)}$ ($p,q$ being polynomials, depending on $x$), which is why unforgeability can be proven. However, the topic of extracting $x$ from $x^x$ is quite difficult (and I can't think of an actual link to DLOG, for example).

Comment: @SDL : $\:$ Is the value `a` actually relevant? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Actually, if $p$ is prime, the problem of finding an $x$ such that $x^x \equiv b \pmod{p}$ is easy.

Comment: If you allow $x>p-1$ it is easy. Can you do it with $0 < x < p-1$?

Comment: @poncho: If the problem is easy, then my question is meaningless.

Comment: @SDL: for prime $p$, it is easy, unless you add in the restriction that $0 < x < p$ as K.G. said.

Comment: @poncho I can't see your solution, even if you allow greater $p$. At least not under the restriction that $x$ is coprime to $p$, and that is necessary if $b\neq0$.

Comment: @tylo: try $x = p^2 - bp + b$.  With that $x$, we have $x^x \equiv b \pmod{p}$ as an identity (assuming, of course, that $p$ is prime).  Why is this?  Hint $y^z \equiv (y \bmod p)^{z \bmod p-1} \pmod{p}$ if $p$ is prime.

Comment: Ah right... I thought of Fermat, but not of throwing CRT on the problem with the coprime moduli. All I could up with involved somehow $p$ as a factor of $x$.

Comment: Would someone care to compose an answer, preferably in _zero knowledge for dummies_ style so that I can catch on?

Answer (score 2):

The original question was:

> Alice knows: $a,b$ and $x$ such that $a^{(x\cdot x)} = b$
>
> Bob knows: $a,b$

and DrLecter referenced [this paper](http://www.di.ens.fr/%7Ebresson/papers/BreSte02.pdf) (fixed the link), which covers the question.

Now, the question was changed to

> Alice knows: $b$ and $x$ such that $x^x=b$;
>
> Bob knows: $b$.

The given structure was:

> ... multiplicative group $G$ which is a subgroup of  $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$

And a sub-question in the comments was, if this is easy if $n$ is prime. The answer in this case is: "It depends".

As poncho pointed out, if $x>n$ is allowed, you can find a $x$, if you consider the exponent and the base independently (let's call the modulus $p$ for being prime):

- $x=b$ mod $p$
- $x=1$ mod $p-1$
- Since $p$ is prime, we can apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get $x= p^2 - bp + b$.

So for $x$ without restrictions, there is no need for a ZKP, because it is easy to calculate the solution from $b$ and $p$ alone.

Now the tricky part: What if $x$ is limited to $x<p$?

- In general, there is no solution, because there is no structure which would be preserved by a function $x\rightarrow x^x$. I can't even think of a way to check if for a given $y$ there exists a $x$, s.t. $x^x=y$.

But what we can prove is that there can be no such zero knowledge proof:

- Bob knows $b$.
- If $b=1$, the solution is $x=p-1$ or $x=1$, this means $x<p-1$.
- If the modulus is prime, he can check if $b$ is a quadratic residue.
- $x$ has a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$, and for every prime factor $x_1$ of $x$, we know that $x^{(x/x_i)}$ has to exist, because $x^a$ is well-defined for every $0\leq a\leq x$, if $0<x<p$.
- If $b$ is a quadratic nonresidue, then there exists no quare root, and we know that $x$ does not contain a factor $2$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$).

A similar approach can be made for every prime factor of $p-1$, because the according exponentiation with this factor is a non-injective function.

This is a contradiction to ZK already, because knowledge of $b$ reveals already some information about $x$.

Comment: I disagree; just because someone can deduce some information from $b$ doesn't disqualify a ZK proof; all it means is that the ZK proof can't reveal anything more.  You can obviously put together a ZK proof by designing a circuit that computes $z^z \bmod p$ for $z<p$, and prove that you know an input $z$ that generates $b$.  While this shows that a ZK proof is possible, it really doesn't answer the question; we are asked for a *simple* proof, and unless your definition of simple is considerably broader than mine, the circuit method wouldn't qualify.

Comment: I covered the basic problem for the lack of ZK too short, I guess: $f(x)=x^x$ is not a homomorphism. It does no preserve any kind of structure. So you can't find what you need in a ZKP: A sort of commitment, which is "related to $x$, but not $x$ itself", and which can be opened in multiple ways. This is similar to why there is no simple ZK proof of knowledge of a preimage of a hash function (except the circuit method).

Comment: I just don't trust the argument "our normal techniques cannot solve this problem, hence this problem cannot be solved".  We know that a complex ZK proof is possible; the standard ways to generate a short proof do not work, however I cannot say that there isn't an alternative short way (that we haven't thought of) that would work.